# Displaying Matrix entries by category

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I'm using Matrix to list my clients services. I've added a 'Promoted Service' category to allow them to filter the services which get shown on the home page.

How can I set each Matrix row with an option to choose that category?

I thought this plug-in was perfect but it actually adds the category to the whole entry as well as the individual row which defeats my initial purpose as it then just shows every category on the home page.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-cat-col

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever happen to fina a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that comes to my mind is using something like [MX Select Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-select)
to retrieve the categories using a sql query and associate one with a matrix row. You'll then be able to search the matrix fields for the category you want, as long as you make the field searchable. Hope this helps.